# Amazon webview is not working properly?

Tags: android, android-webview, amazon-pay

I am making a android app webview.

The problem arises when I try to include an Amazon webview. While going through the payment page of Amazon, after selecting payment mode and while clicking selecting bank, the screen goes white.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This could possibly be a security feature implemented by Amazon to specifically stop the access of the web page from within a webview.

As a replacement, I suggest you use the actual Amazon API to implement the payment features for Amazon. Remember that this is a payment page keeping credit card details of the customer buying the product. So these security features are essential.

Comment: Can you send me the codings of the Amazon api

Comment: Kindly go through this play store link and download it https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.all.in.one.android

Comment: Click on amazon and go through the payment page and do the process to see the small window while selecting bank. I want that. I hope you understand.